# Abrir modal desde respuesta Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quería abrir una ventana modal para poder mostrar un resultado que obtengo a partir de una consulta y construyo con Javascript. Probé a montar una modal y por medio de Jquery llamarla desde el script, pero no funciona, el problema lo tengo al llamarla desde el Javascript.

```
var records = document.getElementById('contINFO');
records.innerHTML = '';
var html = '';
for (i=0; i<feature.length; i++){
    $('.iab, .cerrarInf').hide();
    if(feature[i].get('aphia_id_code') != null){
        records.innerHTML += '<div id="code" class="code">' + feature[i].get('id_code') + '</div>'
        records.innerHTML += '<p class="iob" style="color: rgba(255,69,0,0.6);"><i class="far fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;<span class="fontInf">Observación</span></p>';
    }else{
        records.innerHTML += '';
    }

    if(feature[i].get('imagen') !=null){
        records.innerHTML += '<img id= "btnModal" class = "iob" src=' + feature[i].get('imagen') + '>';
        
    }else{
        records.innerHTML += '<img class = "iobs" src=images/Imagen_dummie.jpg>';
    }   
    if(feature[i].get('name')!= null){
        records.innerHTML += '<h1 class="sub-title iob">' + feature[i].get('name') + '</h1>';
    }else{
        records.innerHTML += '';
    }
}
```

Querría mostrar la imagen en grande dentro de la modal. La propia imagen la uso como botón para abrir la ventana en el html principal

Comment: El problema entonces es que no abre el modal? Y si estas usando JQuery, te recomiendo usar la funcion `append()` para agregar html a un elemento

Comment: Si, el problema es que no abre el modal. A ver, empecé probando a crear la ventana desde javascript, pero como no me la abría al llamarla desde la imagen, probé a hacer una llamada desde una función jquery.